# Form submission with Express, Node, and JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, forms, express

I am very new to **html, express, and node.js** which are the technologies I am currently using to a web app but I'm having a very hard time with form submissions.

**Here is my form** (which is created through a script since its fields vary depending on different factors):

```js
$FormContainer.html('');

var $form = $('<form></form>');
$form.css("action", "/CreateRecordObject");
$form.css("method", "GET");
for (i in data.fields) {
    var $label = $('<strong/>').text(data.fields[i] + ": ");
    var $input = $('<input>');
    $input.css("name", data.fields[i]);
    $input.css("value", " ");
    $input.css("type", "text")
    $label.appendTo($form);
    $('<br>').appendTo($form);
    $input.appendTo($form);
    $('<br><br>').appendTo($form);
}

$('<input type="submit" value="submit">').appendTo($form);

$FormContainer.append($form);
```

This script creates the form in an html file called "/NewRecord.html"

**In the backend**, I have the following route:

```js
app.get('/CreateRecordObject', function(request, response){
  console.log("Inside the CreateRecordObject");
});
```

Nonetheless, the code never enters the "/CreateRecordObject". In fact, after pressing the **submit** button, all that happens is that the URL goes from http://436bb783.ngrok.io/NewRecord to http://436bb783.ngrok.io/NewRecord? adding that question mark at the end and reloading the site. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `FormContainer` from? I mean which script, library, framework etc.

Comment: Form container is the ID of the <main></main> tag in which the actual <form> exists.

Comment: Yeah there was, I just added it again, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`action` and `method` are attributes and not CSS styles. Please change your code to the following:

```
// $form.css("action", "/CreateRecordObject");
// $form.css("method", "GET");

$form.attr("action", "/CreateRecordObject");
$form.attr("method", "GET");
```

```js
$FormContainer = $('#container');
var data = {fields: [1, 2, 3]};
$FormContainer.empty();

var $form = $('<form/>', {"action": "/CreateRecordObject", "method": "GET"});
for (i in data.fields) {
    var $label = $('<strong/>').text(data.fields[i] + ": ");
    var $input = $('<input>', {"name": data.fields[i], "value": "", "type": "text"});
    $label.appendTo($form);
    $('<br>').appendTo($form);
    $input.appendTo($form);
    $('<br><br>').appendTo($form);
}

$('<input type="submit" value="submit">').appendTo($form);
$FormContainer.append($form);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="container"></div>
```

*Source: http://api.jquery.com/attr/*

Comment: Thank you so much! This was the issue, so silly of me!

Comment: Also have a look on this: `$input.css("name", data.fields[i]);` etc. Maybe you should fixed it the same way.